# iOS - NSISEngine crash

Tags: ios, crash-reports

Any idea what causes this crash or how to resolve this ?

```
Thread 11 Crashed:
0   Foundation                           0x000000021c5b6368 ___chooseOutgoingRowHeadForIncomingRowHead_block_invoke + 24
1   Foundation                           0x000000021c479130 __NSIndexSetEnumerate + 752
2   Foundation                           0x000000021c5b37b0 _chooseOutgoingRowHeadForIncomingRowHead + 324
3   Foundation                           0x000000021c5aec7c _minimizeConstantInObjectiveRow + 204
4   Foundation                           0x000000021c3c45f4 -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 232
5   Foundation                           0x000000021c3c4464 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 116
6   Foundation                           0x000000021c3c4228 -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] + 108
7   UIKitCore                            0x000000024840c128 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2012
8   QuartzCore                           0x000000021fece1f0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
9   UIKitCore                            0x0000000248381fa0 -[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayers] + 56
10  QuartzCore                           0x000000021fed3198 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 328
11  QuartzCore                           0x000000021fe360a8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 344
12  QuartzCore                           0x000000021fe64108 CA::Transaction::commit() + 636
13  QuartzCore                           0x000000021fe65288 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 224
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000021b6634b4 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 576
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000021b660904 _pthread_exit + 76
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000021b661508 _pthread_wqthread_exit + 92
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000021b66114c _pthread_wqthread + 356
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000021b663cd4 start_wqthread + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doing an infinite loop in `-[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer]` until your app runs out of memory. Seems to be an issue in the iOS 13 betas when running apps linked against the iOS 13 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the stack trace, you are modifying an UILabel on a background thread (`-[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayersOfLayer]`).

Try to run your app with Main Thread checker enabled (in Product/Scheme/Edit schemes/Diagnostics) :

[image: Main Thread Checker]

When you find the responsible line of code, nest it inside a MainThread dispatch block :

Objc :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // modify the label here
});
```

Swift :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // modify the label here
}
```